# html mysql full-text search query with multiple words

Tags: php, mysql

Here is search engine with php

```
<form action='search_query' method='POST'>
 <input type='text' name='keyword' />
 <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

I want to search the data if a person type two words.

if the keyword is 'red dog'

It should search like this on my-sql.

```
SELECT * FROM `DATA` WHERE `TITLE` LIKE '%red%' and '%dog%';
```

I want to know how to recognize when a person types multiple words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how to recognize when a person types multiple words.

How do you define "multiple words"? Are those words with a space in between? Then [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the input on spaces, and build your query from the result of that.

Comment: yeah there is a space between multiple words. can you explain how to use explode() more?

Comment: @user1220351 No, I'm sorry, please click the link and you'll see the manual.